# How to use subtration in two textbox using a textchange event in vb,net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I put a number in available1.text (100), then I put 22 in txtqty1, the result is 76. Why does this happen?

```vb
Private Sub txtqty1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtqty1.TextChanged

    txtavailable1.Text = txtavailable1.Text - txtqty1.Text

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using `TextChanged` event. As you type the numbers, the texts are changing. Consider the characters as you type them

`100`

Type 2

`100 - 2 = 98`

Type the second 2

`98 - 22 = 76`

Instead, make a button to calculate the math at once

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    txtavailable1.Text = txtavailable1.Text - txtqty1.Text
End Sub
```

You have some other issues such as you're performing math on strings. Instead of doing `string = string - string`, convert to numbers

```vb
txtavailable1.Text = (CInt(txtavailable1.Text) - CInt(txtqty1.Text)).ToString()
```

If you do not want to use a Button, you can add a timer to do the math after 1 second.

```vb
Private doMathTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf doMath, Nothing, -1, -1)

Private Sub txtqty1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtqty1.TextChanged
    doMathTimer.Change(1000, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub doMath(state As Object)
    If txtavailable1.InvokeRequired Then
        txtavailable1.Invoke(Sub() doMath(state), Nothing)
    Else
        txtavailable1.Text = (CInt(txtavailable1.Text) - CInt(txtqty1.Text)).ToString()
    End If
End Sub
```